# javascripts Concurrency is when two or more processes

Tags: javascript

Concurrency is when two or more processes are executing one after the other over two following periods of time

Comment: this is FALSE. What you write is sequential execution. While Concurrency is when two or more processes executes SIMULTANEOUSLY

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here. Concurrency is the task of running and managing the multiple computations at the same time. While parallelism is the task of running multiple computations simultaneously.

Comment: I want know this true or false